# Map Route - HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to ASP.Net MVC and I am getting a 404 error when I'm trying to map route.

I would appreciate if anyone can give me help to find out my error.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult MoviesByRelease(int year,int month)
{

    return Content( year +"/"+ month);
}
```

**RouteConfig**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "MoviesByReleaseDate",
           url: "movies/released/{year}/{month}",
            new { controller = "Movies", action = "MoviesByRelease" }
            , new { year=@"\d{4}" , month=@"\d{2}" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The route looks alright. Do you have view MoviesByRelease in folder Views/Movies? Try removing the constraints from the route and also make the parameters of the controller method nullable, temporarily to see if it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.
I don't have any view MoviesByRelease in folder Views/Movies.
I go to localhost (http://localhost:50921/movies/released/2015/4)
btw, I made the parameters nullable and removed the constraints but still the same issue

Comment: The problem could be in the constraint for month, which can have one or two digits, `month=@"\d{1,2}"`

Comment: But I removed the constraints and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: That is strange. If the controller class name is MoviesController, this should work. just tested on my machine and it is working (in your original version, just with the slight change in month constraint).

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I'm using visual studio 2017 community. 
Is it something that cause the issue?
Also, can you please tell me what changes you made to the constarints?